# Rails says sqlite3 isn't in gem file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to run rake db:migrate but I get many errors as listed below

```
rake aborted!
Gem::LoadError: Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).
/Users/Aeip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:177:in `rescue in spec'
```

I've made sure that sqlite3 is in the gem file and made sure to specify on database.yml which ones to use for development and production but still get this error. My gem file

```
group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
    gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
    gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you `bundle install`? Also, later, you're going to run into problems because you specified `sqlite3` as your database adapter in `production` (in `database.yml`), but you have `gem 'pg'` in the `production` group of your `Gemfile`.

Comment: Yes I ran bundle install and bundle update. And yeah I'm going to change those later. For some reason it is not seeing sqlite3 in the gem file because it is only listed in the development group. It works fine when I move it out of the group

Answer (score 0):

Try running `bundle install rake db:migrate` or `bin/rails db:migrate`.  Those commands should ensure your bundle is properly loaded into your `GEM_PATH`.

Comment: I ran both bundle bundle install and rake db:migrate. Sqlite3 is installed, it is just not finding it in the gem file because it's listed in development group. When I run bundle install, sqlite3 is not listed when it is complete

Comment: Fixed it by running bundle install --with development

Comment: Glad you fixed it!  AFAIK `bundle install` installs for all environments unless you have an environmental variable specified like BUNDLE_WITH or BUNDLE_WITHOUT.